# Recommended way of parsing a Form into an URLSearchParam object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning typescript translating an old project from JS to TS. I'm having problems with this function that is called when a submit button is pressed in a login form with the default behaviour prevented. When called, the event is passed as parameter.

In the body of the function I'm trying to parse the content of the `<form>` into an `URLSearchParam` object.

```
function sendLogin(e: SubmitEvent) {
    let URLSP: URLSearchParams;
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
        URLSP = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(e.target));
...
```

This approach (the one of the original JS app) is clean but doesn't work because TS complains about: `URLsearchParams` doesn't accept `FormData` datatype as argument.

```
function sendLogin(e: SubmitEvent) {
    let URLSP: URLSearchParams;
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
        let A = new FormData(e.target);
        let B = [...A.entries()];
        let URLSP = new URLSearchParams(B);
    }
...
```

This second approach also doesn't work because `B` has `[String,FormDataEntryValue][]` datatype. `URLSearchParams` accepted datatypes are `string | URLSearchParams | string[][] | Record<string, string>`.

Which would be the cleanest way to parse my `<form>` into an `URLSearchParam` object in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` is actually not full compatible with `URLSearchParams` contructor, sadly. See [Typescript #30584](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30584#issuecomment-890515551) for more info.

That issue thread has a few workarounds, such as:

```
const convertedFormEntries = Array.from(
  formData,
  ([key, value]) => (
    [key, typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name]
  ),
);
```

Which seems to work, as far as I can tell.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiATgWxgXhgExMArsgUzCgDphECBDKAgUQBsDDiAKAcgRTYEoBuAKFCRYnZABFqldDDAEA7jABiScZJaju-QeGgwhANwKIamZSlrFEASwIRpAQUSJKATxJxEIZC34x4KiShKABpfGBYAbQBrAhdgmH1KelwCAF1udAA+cLC-aNj4qBcABwIQOASklPQ0DDZoazAAczYYAH5K5IIYAC5OlJIwSkJUsO5Qvi0hXQgqRGAACwAFSmdkOwxZBQBVACUAGQBlOcWVtYgWAyMTM2QLKGtbPiA)

Comment: Works in my project too, thanks. It's a shame that both types aren't compatible. There are plans to make them compatible in the future?

Comment: Not according to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30584#issuecomment-893530491, no